# Setting height of a gridView item as double of width

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-xml

The width of the grid item will change when the screen size changes.
I need to set the height of the grid item as double of the width of the grid item.
That is , if the width of grid `item=25dp` height must be `50dp`.

**This is  getView funciton of my Adapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView no=new TextView(context);
    no.setText(position+"");
    // I need to set double of width instead of 150
    no.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,150));
}
```

Updating....
**My Complete getView**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int pos=position;
    View layout=null;
    itemWidth=gridView.getColumnWidth();
    layout=layout.inflate(context, R.layout.exam_grid_item, null);
    TextView examName=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.examNameTextView);
    TextView examStatus=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewExamStatus);
    LinearLayout itemContainer = (LinearLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.itemContainar);

    itemContainer.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,itemWidth*2));

    ImageView statusImage=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.examStatusImageView);
    examName.setText("exam name"+itemHeight+"\n"+itemWidth);

    statusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tic);
    examStatus.setText("Attended");

    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by changing the view item size programmatically in getView() in your adapter. I've done it myself.

Something like this should work:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ....

        // Get item width by using getColumnWidth.
        // By doing this you support dynamic column width in grid.    
        final int columnWidth = gridView.getColumnWidth();

        // Set your views height here 
        final int columnHeight = 50; // This is in px

        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = (AbsListView.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = columnWidth;
        lp.height = columnHeight;

        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return view;
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: @JITHINGOPAL can you update your question with your whole getView() then? I'm not sure if you're returning the textview or if its located in some kind of wrapper. I'm using the code above today and it's working. So maybe I understood the question wrong. But some more code would help.

Comment: Its not the exact width is return.   its in pixel I tried to implement that directly an convert it into dp also , but wont work

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass (for example DoubleWidthTextView) that extends TextView as such:

```
public class DoubleWidthTextView  extends TextView {

  ...

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = 2 * width;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
  }

  ...

}
```

And use it instead of TextView.

Comment: Thankyou , but That is not practical in my case. I need to change the items into imageView, LinearLayout , etc  any other solutions?

Comment: Instead of `TextView`, you can extend any other class: ImageView, LinearLayout, etc...